# How to Validate the Date of Birth IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, validation

Hi in my application i have a registration form in my application and I'm validating all fields like email and phone number. But i want to validate this DOB in format like `DD/MM/YY`. I'm using else if condition checking for my validation i want do same for DOB

I'm validation with else if condition like this.

```
   - (IBAction)send:(id)sender {
   if ([self phonevalidate:[ph text]]!= 1){
       UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"pls enter valid 10 digit number" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alert1 show];
       [alert1 release];
   }

  else if ([self validateEmail:[emd text]]!= 1){
       UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"pls enter valid email id" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alert1 show];
       [alert1 release];
    }
```

My validation function for phone.

```
    -(BOOL)phonevalidate:(NSString *)phh
 {
      NSString *phoneRegex = @"[0-9]{10}";
      NSPredicate *phoneTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex];

      return  [phoneTest evaluateWithObject:phh];
 }
```

I'm not using the UIDate Picker i have UITextfield for the DOB i want validate with UITextfield itself.Like the above i want to validate the DOB please tell me how to validate the DOB and check int else if condition.

Thanks.

Comment: Your date (DOB) is String date or NSDate  formate ?

Comment: Might not serve your needs, but have you considered using a `UIDatePicker` instead ? That way, not only can you format the user's selected DOB as per your needs, but also, is more pleasing UI-wise.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer please tell is there any possibilities to implement the uidate picker to uitextview

Comment: Gimme 2 minutes. You mean UITextField, right? Not UITextView?

Comment: @n00bProgrammer UITextfied

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDITED:**

Assume  that b'date is

```
NSString *dateOfBirth = @"22/03/14";
```

And this is method for check b'date is valid or not ?

```
-(BOOL) isValidateDOB:(NSString *) dateOfBirth
{
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];
    NSDate *validateDOB = [format dateFromString:dateOfBirth];
    if (validateDOB != nil) 
       return YES;
    else
       return NO;
}
```

In above method `[format setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];` and `setDateFormat` is very important in your case:

Now you can check it as like,

```
if([self isValidateDOB:dateOfBirth])
{ 
   // b"date is valid;
}
else
{
  // b"date is not valid;
}
```

Comment: i have tried your code its giving error in else part like excepted expression i have used braces but its still showing the error pls tell me how to resolve this

Comment: can please tell me how to check not ivalidateDOB is notequal to dateofbrith

Comment: if "ivalidateDOB is notequal to dateofbrith" then `else` part is executed.. check my answer is edited and also check it with my demo project, it's working well for me.

Comment: im validating more fields so have used the else if condition if im validatin only dob is this code is f9 but im validating so many fields thats y im asking please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Let's try below codes:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"DD/MM/YY"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12/12/2014"];

If (date) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"Valid date");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIDatePicker` for this :

Initialize like this :

```
UIDatePicker datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];

datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
```

Then, set the `inputView` of your `textField` (the one that takes DOB as input) :

```
yourDOBtextField.inputView = datePicker;
```

Then, implement `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method for `UITextField`:

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


    if (textField == yourDOBtextField) {

        NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yy";
        yourDOBtextField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];

        [dateFormatter release];
    }
}
```

That's it.

Comment: pls tell me where i have to use initialize the UIdate picker do ihave inside any function or can initialize outside

Comment: You should make it a global object. Declare in `.h` like `UIDatePicker* datePicker;`. Then in `viewDidLoad` add the rest of the code (Remove the `UIDatePicker*` from `viewDidLoad`). Then set the delegate of your `textField` like `yourDOBtextField.delegate = self;`. Set your `.h` as `UITextFieldDelegate`. and you are done. :)